# Move constructor deleted vs not generated

Tags: c++11, move-semantics

Consider this code:

```
struct A
{
    A() = default;
    A(const A&) = default;
};
```

If I'm correct, the compiler will automatically generated a default deconstructor. However, it will not do so for the movement constructor.

However, the above code allows me to do this:

```
int main()
{
    A a1;
    A a2 = std::move(a1);
    return 0;
}
```

My question is: why?

If I modify the definition of `struct A` as follows:

```
struct A
{
    A() = default;
    A(const A&) = default;
    A(A&&) = delete;
};
```

then `A a2 = std::move(a1)` does not compile, which makes sense.

So, what's the difference between deleting a constructor and *not generating it*? Or does the compiler generate the move constructor anyway?

Comment: `A a2 = std::move(a1);` can happily use the copy constructor when the move constructor is unavailable. An overload resolution is performed; the move constructor would be a better match if it existed, but of course if it doesn't, then copy constructor is used as the only choice.

Comment: Ok, but apperently, the copy constructor is not used when I delete the move constructor... It does not compile.

Comment: A function declared as deleted participates in overload resolution. If selected as the best match, the program is ill-formed. Whereas the function that's not declared at all doesn't, of course, participate in overload resolution.